# How to do the image fill the text - the same size always - xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, layout, xamarin.forms

I am trying to do a button with a image, and each button has a text inside...but I don't know so much about xamarin forms, I'm a beginner
And my images is little while the text is bigger than it...

I am using a grid...and inside it one other grid with 1 colunm and 1 row for each button (Image and texts)
I neet the image (that is my button) get the size of the texts that is inside it

[image]

My xml at the moment:

```
<!-- Buttons grid-->
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="20,20,20,20" RowSpacing="30" ColumnSpacing="10" BackgroundColor="Aquamarine" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <!--One of my buttons grid, there are 4 others as this one--> 
 <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Gray">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image Source="comochegarbtn.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="MapaClique"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Image Source="Location.png" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                <Label Text="Como Chegar" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{Binding labelsfont}"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

In android I could solve that using wrap_content
But here, in xamarin forms, I don't know how to solve it
The gray part is the grid item size

Comment: do you need to wrap the text according to image width or stretch image according to the text size?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the exact size of the Text to be the width of your Image then you will have to use [RelativeLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/).

In the [RelativeLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/) for the Image width use `RelativeToView`. 
This is similar to the Relative Layout in Android.

```
<RelativeLayout>

            <Image RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Type=RelativeToView, ElementName=myStacklayout,Property=Width,Factor=1}" Source="comochegarbtn.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="MapaClique"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>

            <StackLayout x:Name="myStacklayout" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Image Source="Location.png" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                <Label Text="Como Chegar" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" Style="{Binding labelsfont}"/>
            </StackLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Using one or 2 relative layouts won't affect you much. But if you think it does you can write a custom render and create a complex button in the native layer.

Comment: 1. Jason Smith doesn't recommend Relative Layout. 2. If you use relative to view how do you know what size of the image on screen? Please add some code to make this answer useful

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love relative layout :-) but the code is still required for an answer :-)

Comment: hmmmmm
I tried it...but I am not sure about it
in the relative layout I have Type=RelativeToParent,
                             Property=Height,
                             Factor=0.5,
                             Constant=-100

If in the property I use HEIGHT 
then The height of the view will be relative to parent height?
And factor and constant? what do they do?

Comment: than you guys
@YuriS my code is as I posted here...I didn't put a value to the size

Comment: The childreen and the parent need to be inside the relative or only the child?
Thank you very much

Comment: That was @RohitVipinMathwes answer, I will let him to answer. Joyce, just a small suggestion: you should start accepting answers then people will help you more. Out of last 10 questions you accepted one. Were other answers useless?

Comment: Hmm, using Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" in relative layout without declaring Grid. I am wondering how that is going to work but I might be wrong...

Comment: I just picked the code the OP had, removed the grid. It had nothing to do with answer.